# How to make my username and password dynamic so I don't need to hardcode it. I believe this can be done using a function if anyone can assist

Tags: python, function

#Please see code. As of now I have USER:PASS defined as variables.

```
# What function can I add to this code to make username and password dynamic?

from pymongo import MongoClient
from bson.json_util import dumps, loads
import urllib.parse

# A MongoDB instance for Python
mongo_client = MongoClient(
    f'zzzzzzxx',tls=True,
   xxxe)

# A database instance
db = mxx
result = db.xxxxx.find()

print(result.next())
```

Comment: dynamic based on what?

Comment: The question is unclear. You don't have to hard-code those values. You can read them from a configuration file, environment variables or command-line arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want not to expose them in your python script you can add it to environment variable and read it from there.

Example:
In terminal (linux based):

```
export USER_NAME="your-username"
export USER_PASSWRD="your-password"
```

In windows CMD:

```
set USER_NAME=your-username
set USER_PASSWORD=your-password
```

Remember to close and reopen the editor to use the updated variables.

Then in your python script you can read them as follows:

```py
import os
user=os.environ['USER_NAME']
passwrd=os.environ['USER_PASSWRD']
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating environment variables on your system, you could create a `.env` file in your project & add your configuration in there, like:

```
DB_USER_NAME="JohnDoe"
DB_PASSWORD="veryLongSecurePassword123!"
```

You can process this `.env` file with [python-dotenv](https://pypi.org/project/python-dotenv/):

```py
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv()
```

This allows you even more advanced configuration options in the future for deployments or developer customization by using a `.env.defaults` file & overwriting it if needed with a custom `.env` file, that is not checked into your git repository.

Dotenv also works on all operating systems and can be used with multiple different programming languages (handy if you want to use the same configuration file for your frontend and backend).